# Split Filename Up to Define Variables

Tags: date, split, terminal, filenames

I have a script I created to help with converting a video then uploading it to our website. Our videos all have a standard format for their filename to help with setting them up correctly (day, month, year; i.e. 09OCT2013.m4v). They get filed into directories from year to month to day (i.e. 2013/oct/09OCT2013/09OCT2013.m4v). Right now, my script opens by asking for user input for the year then month then the actual file name for the folder. What I want to do is take the file that has already been created, drop it into the script, then have the script take it apart and put it in the appropriate file (i.e. drop the file 12JUN2012.m4v into the script and the script automatically puts it into 2012/jun/12JUN2012/). Is there any possible way to do this in terminal? Please let me know if any part of my question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using `bash`:

```
for file in "$@"
do
     dd=${file:0:2}
     mm=${file:2:3}
     yy=${file:5:4}
     mv "$file" "$yy/$mm/$file"
done
```

If the file needs to be moved further, or is supplied with more pathname, you can adjust the script, but the basic idea of splitting the last component of the file name up using the substring notation is good.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I had to find a way to get the file path off of the file itself, but once I figured that out, I was good to go.

Comment: `basename` is the classic technique for removing the path (and optionally a suffix too), and `dirname` is the classic technique for getting the directory from the path.  These days, `${file##*/}` works about the same as `basename` (except for removing the suffix), and `${file%/*}` does as `dirname` except when there isn't a directory name (`dirname` yields `.` but `${file%/*}` yields the file name).