# Parse filenames into touch command on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, filenames, command-line-arguments

I have a large number of photos on my machine where I'd like to parse the standard naming convention I have created for each file, and then pipe it to the `touch` command.

For example, I have these files:

```
2016-08-06-00h28m34.jpg
2016-08-06-00h28m35.jpg
2016-08-06-00h28m36.jpg
```

I would like to generate (and then run) the following commands:

```
touch -t 201608060028.34 2016-08-06-00h28m34.jpg
touch -t 201608060028.35 2016-08-06-00h28m35.jpg
touch -t 201608060028.36 2016-08-06-00h28m36.jpg
```

I can do this manually in a text editor, but it's extremely time-consuming, due to the number of files in each directory. I could also do it in C# and run it over my LAN, but that seems like overkill. Heck, I can even do this in SQL Server, but ... it's OS X and I'm sure there's a simple command-line thing I'm missing.

I've looked at [Windows version of Unix touch command to modify a file's modification date from filename part](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24062726), and [Split Filename Up to Define Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19340794),  but I can't seem to figure out how to add in the period for the seconds portion of the script, plus I don't want to add the batch script to each of the hundreds of folders I have.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're kinda asking someone to write a script for you.  Why should they?  I would do it in python, BTW, because that's my go-to language for more-than-shell-scripting and is cross-platform.  And when you say you can do it in SQL Server, you are not speaking the truth :)

Comment: I can do it in SQL Server with xp_cmdshell, so, yeah. I can do it in PowerShell as well, but again, wrong platform for OS X. Mark's answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks all the same for your feedback!

Comment: But SQL Server only runs under Windows doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server (presently) only runs under Windows. I have a Windows machine on the same network as my MacBook Pro. You must have missed the phrase "I could also do it in C# and run it over my LAN" from my question. It doesn't matter. Mark answered the question. This digression is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple Option**

I presume you are trying to set the filesystem time to match the EXIF capture time of thousands of photos. There is a tool for that, which runs on OSX, Linux (and Windows if you must). It is called `jhead` and I installed it on OSX using `homebrew` with:

```
brew install jhead
```

There may be other ways to install it - [jhead website](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/).

Please make a back up before trying this, or try it out on a small subset of your files, as I may have misunderstood your needs!

Basically the command to set the filesystem timestamp to match the EXIF timestamp on a single file is:

```
jhead -ft SomeFile.jpg
```

So, if you wanted to set the timestamps for all files in `$HOME/photos/tmp` and all subdirectories, you would do:

```
find $HOME/photos/tmp -iname \*.jpg -exec jhead -ft {} \;
```

**Option not requiring any extra software**

Failing that, you could do it with **Perl** which is installed on OSX by default anyway:

```
find . -name \*.jpg | perl -lne 'my $a=$_; s/.*(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+).*/$1$2$3$4$5.$6/ && print "touch -t $_\ \"$a\"" '
```

which gives this sort of output on my machine:

```
touch -t 201608060028.34 "./2016-08-06-00h28m34.jpg"
touch -t 201608060028.35 "./2016-08-06-00h28m35.jpg"
touch -t 201501060028.35 "./tmp/2015-01-06-00h28m35.jpg"
```

and if that looks good on your machine, you could send those commands into `bash` to be executed like this:

```
find . -name \*.jpg | perl -lne 'my $a=$_;s/.*(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)h(\d+)m(\d+).*/$1$2$3$4$5.$6/ && print "touch -t $_\ \"$a\"" ' | bash -x
```

And, for the Perl purists out there, yes, I know Perl could do the `touch` itself and save invoking a whole `touch` process per file, but that would require modules and explanation and a heap of other extraneous stuff that is not really necessary for a one-off, or occasional operation.

Comment: I have a number of photos that are scanned, so there's no EXIF data in them at all. Otherwise I could easily have used that to set the file properties, as you suggest. The perl solution works very well, thank you. I've accepted your answer.